# Set the default value for the key of the function object parameter

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I need to transfer some props into my component.

```js
type Props = {
  icon: number,
  onChangeText: Function,
  onEndEditing: Function,
  placeholder: string,
  secureTextEntry?: boolean
};
export default function LRInput(
  props: Props = { ...props, secureTextEntry: false } // I've tried to do it in this way, but it hasn't worked 
) { /*function body*/ }
```

You can see that secureTextEntry is an optional parameter. So, I want to define some default value for this prop. How can I do this?

Comment: `{ ...props, secureTextEntry = false } `

Comment: Thanks, but I changed your variant on the {secureTextEntry = false, ...props}: Props, because I had this errors:
"Parsing error: Rest element must be last element" and
"Rest property must be final property of an object pattern".
And I added :Props, because I got "Missing type annotation for destructuring." warning.

Comment: Right, rest syntax must be the last `{secureTextEntry = false, ...props}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use destructuring at all, rather put the optional property on a new object:

```
export default function LRInput(props: Props) {
     const defaultedProps: Props = { secureTextEntry: false, ...props };
    /* function body */
}
```

Comment: Thanks) But could you explain why it is better than the previous answer?

Comment: @Eugene `secureTextEntry` is now part of `defaultedProps`, unlike when you use destructuring where it is *not* part of the rest object.

Comment: Or I can write `export default function LRInput(props: Props) {
  props = { secureTextEntry: false, ...props };
  console.log(props.secureTextEntry);
}`. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it while destructuring unfortunately, (or fortuntately?)

```js
type Props = {
  icon: number,
  onChangeText: Function,
  onEndEditing: Function,
  placeholder: string,
  secureTextEntry?: boolean
};
function LRInput(
  { secureTextEntry = false, ...props }: Props
) { console.log(secureTextEntry) }

LRInput({ icon: 5 })
LRInput({ icon: 5, secureTextEntry: true })
```

**Edit**

To address your concern of the default value being after the rest of the props, it is not an issue with typescript set to target es5 as the rest syntax gets transpiled away into something like below,

```
function LRInput(_a) { 
    var _b = _a.secureTextEntry;
    var secureTextEntry = _b === void 0 ? false : _b; 

    /* code to handle rest omitted */

    console.log(secureTextEntry); 
}
```

As you see, with the above transformation the order of the spread does not matter and my code snippet behaves correctly as a result. However, since it makes no logical sense to capture the "rest" of the keys before the others, the ES2018 standard and Typescript require you to place it behind the destructured keys `{ secureTextEntry = false, ...rest }`.

(I missed this the first time because I copy edited your code and it ran fine since the typescript compiler on this site is set to emit even if it detects "compile errors" and since I wasn't actually using `...props` inside the function, I didn't realise that the rest parameter transformation wasn't working properly. You should see the [transpilation in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Props%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20icon%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20onChangeText%3A%20Function%2C%0D%0A%20%20onEndEditing%3A%20Function%2C%0D%0A%20%20placeholder%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20secureTextEntry%3F%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20LRInput(%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20...props%2C%20secureTextEntry%20%3D%20false%20%7D%3A%20Props%0D%0A)%20%7B%20console.log(secureTextEntry)%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ALRInput(%7B%20icon%3A%205%20%7D)%0D%0ALRInput(%7B%20icon%3A%205%2C%20secureTextEntry%3A%20true%20%7D)) yourself.)

Comment: Thanks)
Please, correct me if I'm wrong. If I call the function in this way, LRInput({ icon: 5 }), I have secureTextEntry = false because this property is missing in the rest (...props). But if I call the function in this way, LRInput({ icon: 5, secureTextEntry: true }), I have secureTextEntry = false firstly, but next I have secureTextEntry = true, because I have a property with the same name in the rest (...props) and it replaces false on true.

Comment: Ahh yes, normally I would naturally place it at the end but since I copy-edited your original question, I missed it. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your really accurate explanation)